# How to bind a collection to datagrid column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to bind the **Version** collection to my datagrid -

```
public ObservableCollection<Version> versions { get; set; }

public class Version
{
     public string versionName { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<Revision> Revisions { get; set; }
}

public class Revision
{
    public string revNumber{ get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

The datagrid should look like this -

[image: Version Datagrid]

I know how to bind a simple collection to a datagrid. but my requirement is to  display multiple revisions for a single versionName. I dont know how to do that.

below is my XAMl code -

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="DataGridVersion" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=versions}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="25.2,82,22,19" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Version" Binding = "{Binding versionName }" Width="0.35*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Revision"  Binding = "{Binding Revisions }" Width=" 0.2*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Comment" Binding = "{Binding comment }" Width="0.6*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with an `ItemsControl`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="DataGridVersion" RowHeaderWidth="0" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=versions}" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="25.2,82,22,19" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Version" Binding = "{Binding versionName }" Width="0.35*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Revisions" Width=" 0.2*" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Revisions}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding revNumber}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Comment}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you want an actual revision and comment column in your `DataGrid`, you should bind to a `ObservableCollection<T>` where the type `T` contains three properties; `versionName`, `revNumber` and `Comment`. You will then have to transform your data:

```
var transformed = versions
    .SelectMany(x => x.Revisions.Select(y => new { x.versionName, y.revNumber, y.Comment }))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but my requirement is different. your solution partially fixes my problem but I want each revision numbers to be selectable. using ur solution I can fill the data in the grid but individual revision number cant be selected. Also, It would be very helpful if you can provide me the solution using ListView . Just now i realised Listview looks pretty good as comparised to datagrid

Comment: just now I realised the last line. my bad!

Answer (score 3):

You should check the [Grouping function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control) of the Datagrid control.

EDIT: seeing your data structure, you could also create a DatagridTemplateColumn and add a listbox with its itemssource bound to the Revisions property.